# Create file and add timestamp

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a list files from a directory, and use the following script:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\windows\SysWOW64\PKG_LOGS' |
    Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime |
    sort LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Out-File C:\Users\amhowar\Desktop\Packages_Dates.txt
```

This works very well, although I would like to append with a timestamp.  I tried this, but PS doesn't like the `+`.  Any suggestions?

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\windows\SysWOW64\PKG_LOGS' |
    Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime |
    sort LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Out-File "C:\Users\amhowar\Desktop\Packages_Dates_" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd") + ".txt"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Subexpression:](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2013/09/25/powershell-sub-expressions/)

```
Out-File $("C:\Users\amhowar\Desktop\Packages_Dates_" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd") +".txt")
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 4):

You need a grouping expression if you want to use a concatenation operation as an argument to a cmdlet:

```
... | Out-File ("C:\Users\amhowar\Desktop\Packages_Dates_" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd") +".txt")
```

Another option would be nesting the `Get-Date` call inside the string with a subexpression:

```
... | Out-File "C:\Users\amhowar\Desktop\Packages_Dates_$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd").txt"
```

Comment: Thanks!  I love how there are many ways to do the same thing in PowerShell.